# 3rd part widget does not update when navigating using the Next.js link

Tags: next.js, widget

I am having issue with Feefo Product Reviews widget.

I am using Next.js "^12.3.0" with page router and React "^17.0.2".

Expected behaviour:

1. Product reviews are visible below the product title.
2. When I navigate to a different product page the reviews update for that new product.

I have managed to display the reviews correctly for initial product, however whenever I go to a different product page from 'current product' page the reviews are not updating and I can still see the previous product's reviews.

I am using next link to navigate.

Using html a tag instead solves this but I would like to use next link instead.

In order to install the feefo widget you need to add script below:

```
<Script
     type="text/javascript"
     src="https://api.feefo.com/api/javascript/user"
     async
/>
```

And to display the actual widget this code snippet

```
<div
    className="feefo-product-stars-widget mb-1 review-stars"
    data-product-sku={product.sku}
    data-parent-product-sku={product.sku}
/>
```

I assume this is because next.js navigation does not actually doing a hard reload and the previous widget is cached.

Do you have any ideas how to trigger refetch of the widget data without compromising the next js performance?